# What is the difference between Bdseq and Seq number in MQTT Sparkplug

Tags: mqtt

I am using C# Sparkplug library and trying to publish data. I need a clarification about BdSeq number and message Seq number.

Should we use only one variable for seq and BdSeq number? Start at 0 and increment till 255 when publishing NBIRTH, DBIRTH, NDATA and DDATA?

what is the difference between BdSeq number and message Seq number.

Also, I have seen the metric for Bdseqnum takes a datatype of UInt64 in the document. If the limit is only till 255, why are we using UInt64?

Thanks.

Comment: This looks like a very Sparkplug specific question, but there doesn't seem to be a Sparkplug tag so it's unlikely that there is a community on SO.

Comment: There is no community related to Sparkplug. So I posted it here in case people might know sparkplug who also knows MQTT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *bdSeq* number and the *seq* number have different uses and should not share the same variable.

The *seq* number should be part of every DBIRTH/NBIRTH/DDATA/NDATA/DDEATH message. It is used to ensure in-order delivery of the messages to any consumer of the data.

The *bdSeq* is used to track the overall session of the Sparkplug client. It is a number is a special Metric that is only present in the NBIRTH/NDEATH messages. It is used to match a NDEATH (published by the MQTT Server on behalf of a disconnected Sparkplug client) with a previously published NBIRTH message. The consumers of the data use the NDEATH to know that the Sparkplug client is offline. The reason this is necessary is because it is possible that a Sparkplug client might lose their connection, reconnect, and publish a new NBIRTH before the MQTT Server publishes the NDEATH from the previous session. In this case the new NBIRTH will contain a new *bdSeq* number and any subsequent NDEATH messages with old *bdSeq* numbers can be ignored.